# OpenCV - Python Bag Of Words(BoW) generating histograms from dictionary

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to create an image classifier in Python OpenCV 3.2.0 using keypoints and the bag of words technique. After some reading I found that I could peform this as follows

1. Extract image descriptors using AKAZE
2. Perform k-means clustering on the descriptors to generate the dictionary
3. Generate histograms of images based on dictionary
4. Train SVM using histograms

I managed to do steps 1 and 2 but have gotten stuck on steps 3 and 4.

I generated the histograms by using the labels returned by k-means clustering successfully (I think). However, when I wanted to use new test data that was not used to generate the dictionary I had some unexpected results. I tried to use a FLANN matcher like in this [tutorial](https://picoledelimao.github.io/blog/2016/01/31/is-it-a-cat-or-dog-a-neural-network-application-in-opencv/) but the results I get from generating the histograms from the label data does not match the data returned from the FLANN matching.

I load up the images:

```
dictionary_size = 512
# Loading images
imgs_data = []
# imreads returns a list of all images in that directory
imgs = imreads(imgs_path)
for i in xrange(len(imgs)):
    # create a numpy to hold the histogram for each image
    imgs_data.insert(i, np.zeros((dictionary_size, 1)))
```

I then create an array of descriptors (desc):

```
def get_descriptors(img, detector):
    # returns descriptors of an image
    return detector.detectAndCompute(img, None)[1]

# Extracting descriptors
detector = cv2.AKAZE_create()

desc = np.array([])
# desc_src_img is a list which says which image a descriptor belongs to
desc_src_img = []
for i in xrange(len(imgs)):
    img = imgs[i]
    descriptors = get_descriptors(img, detector)
    if len(desc) == 0:
        desc = np.array(descriptors)
    else:
        desc = np.vstack((desc, descriptors))
    # Keep track of which image a descriptor belongs to
    for j in range(len(descriptors)):
        desc_src_img.append(i)
# important, cv2.kmeans only accepts type32 descriptors
desc = np.float32(desc)
```

The descriptors are then clustered using k-means:

```
# Clustering
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 0.01)
flags = cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS
# desc is a type32 numpy array of vstacked descriptors
compactness, labels, dictionary = cv2.kmeans(desc, dictionary_size, None, criteria, 1, flags)
```

Then I create histograms for each image using the labels returned from k-means:

```
# Getting histograms from labels
size = labels.shape[0] * labels.shape[1]
for i in xrange(size):
    label = labels[i]
    # Get this descriptors image id
    img_id = desc_src_img[i]
    # imgs_data is a list of the same size as the number of images
    data = imgs_data[img_id]
    # data is a numpy array of size (dictionary_size, 1) filled with zeros
    data[label] += 1

ax = plt.subplot(311)
ax.set_title("Histogram from labels")
ax.set_xlabel("Visual words")
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency")
ax.plot(imgs_data[0].ravel())
```

This outputs a histogram like this [image: Label Histogram] which is very evenly distributed and what I expect.

I then attempt to do the same thing on the same image but using FLANN:

```
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher_create()
matcher.add(dictionary)
matcher.train()

descriptors = get_descriptors(imgs[0], detector)

result = np.zeros((dictionary_size, 1), np.float32)
# flan matcher needs descriptors to be type32
matches = matcher.match(np.float32(descriptors))
for match in matches:
    visual_word = match.trainIdx
    result[visual_word] += 1

ax = plt.subplot(313)
ax.set_title("Histogram from FLANN")
ax.set_xlabel("Visual words")
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency")
ax.plot(result.ravel())
```

This outputs a histogram like this [image: FLANN Histogram] which is very unevenly distributed and does not match up with the first histogram.

You can view the full code and images on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/siphomateke/ddd61116fd7b26c3a7c817f7dcea8581). Change "imgs_path" (line 20) to a directory with images before running it.

Where am I going wrong? Why are the histograms so different? How do I generate the histograms for new data using the dictionary?

As a side note I tried using the OpenCV BOW implementation but found another issue where it gave the error: "*_queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescType in function cv::BFMatcher::knnMatchImpl*" and that's why I am trying to implement it myself. If someone could provide a working example using Python OpenCV BOW and AKAZE then that would be just as good.

Comment: Please do not link a GitHub repository, but provide [a small example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in code blocks.

Comment: @lukegv Updated as per your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you cannot train a FlannBasedMatcher using a dictionary before hand as show below:

```
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher_create()
matcher.add(dictionary)
matcher.train()
```

However you can pass the `dictionary` in when matching like this:

```
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher_create()

...

matches = matcher.match(np.float32(descriptors), dictionary)
```

I am not entirely sure why this. Perhaps its that the `train` method is only meant to be used by the `match` method as hinted in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744451/descriptormatcher-opencv-train).

Also according to the [opencv docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#descriptormatcher-match) the parameters for `match` are:

> - queryDescriptors – Query set of descriptors.
> - trainDescriptors – Train set of descriptors. This set is not added to the train descriptors collection stored in the class object.
> - matches – Matches. If a query descriptor is masked out in mask , no match is added for this descriptor. So, matches size may be smaller than the query descriptors count.

So I guess you are just supposed to pass the `dictionary` in as `trainDescriptors` because that is what it is.

If anyone could shed more light on this it would be appreciated.

Here are the results after using the above method:

[image: The two histograms; one generated from labels and one generated from the flann matches]

You can see the full updated code [here](https://gist.github.com/siphomateke/61f383a77883959ce802116141b4cd7d).